# Separar mensaje de notificación de evento de controles

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-forms

Trabajo con Visual Studio 2019, Windows Forms, C#
Tengo un formulario que hace de mensaje de notificaciones casi siempre lo llamo desde un evento pero a la hora que se muestra deseo que sea independiente a evento que lo llamo, he notado si por ejemplo lo llamo desde un evento keypress de un Text Box se muestra la notificación pero recupero el foco cuando el form notificación desaparece o se cierra y eso es lo que no me gusta.

Este es el código que ocupo.

```
public FrmAlertas(string message, AlertType type) : this()
    {
        lblMensaje.Text = message;
        switch (type)
        {
            case AlertType.Success:
                this.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(46, 204, 113);
                picIcon.Image = imageList1.Images[0];
                break;
            case AlertType.Info:
                this.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(133, 193, 233);
                picIcon.Image = imageList1.Images[1];
                break;
            case AlertType.Warning:
                this.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(244, 208, 63);
                picIcon.Image = imageList1.Images[2];
                break;
            case AlertType.Error:
                this.BackColor = Color.Red;
                picIcon.Image = imageList1.Images[3];
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    public static void Alertas(string message, AlertType type)
    {
        var argMensaje = new ConstructorArgument("message", message);
        var argType = new ConstructorArgument("type", type);
        CompositionRoot.Resolve<FrmAlertas>(argMensaje, argType).Show();
    }
```

Lo llamo de la siguiente manera

```
public void Guardar()
    {
        try
        {
            var entity = new Cliente()
            {
                ClienteId = string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtClienteId.Text)
                    ? 0
                    : Convert.ToInt32(txtClienteId.Text),
                TipoIdentificacionId = (int)(cboTipoIdentificacion.SelectedValue),
                Numero = txtNumero.Text,
                RazonSocial = txtRazonSocial.Text,
                Direccion = txtDireccion.Text,
                Telefono = txtTelefono.Text,
                Email = txtEmail.Text
            };
            _saCliente.Create(entity);
            txtClienteId.Text = Convert.ToString(entity.ClienteId);
            FrmAlertas.Alertas("Success", AlertType.Success);
            LoadDgvCliente();
            Opener.HabilitarBotonesDespuesGuardar(true);
            //Opener.MostrarReloj();
        }
        catch (CustomException e)
        {
            FrmAlertas.Alertas(e.Message, AlertType.Info);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            FrmAlertas.Alertas(e.Message, AlertType.Error);
        }
    }
```

¿Sera posible que al momento que lo muestre sea independiente al evento que lo llamo?

Saludos!!!

Comment: No veo que tiene que ver el evento. En el codigo que nos muestras el metodo static Alertas() no se relaciona con ningun evento

Answer (score 0):

siempre que ejecutes el evento donde lo llamas el método, se ejecutara las instrucciones que que tengas.

Por lo cual no va ser independiente, a menos que le coloques una validación para cuando se ejecute el evento llame o no al método.